# Add additional text to end of array element

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am trying to get VBSCript to pass "configure call gcid splitArray(x) delete" for each element in the array. Instead im getting "configure call gcid splitArray(x)" until the last element which will comeback as "configure call gcid splitArray(x) delete".

I am some what new to scripting, thanks in advance.

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Test"
 APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
 SCROLL="yes"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>
<script language="vbscript">


Sub ClearCalls
  serv2 = editor.serv1.value
  call2 = editor.call1.value
  splitArray = Split(call2, chr(10), -1, 0)
  set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run "cmd.exe"
  Delay 1
Shell.SendKeys "telnet -f c:\results.txt " & serv2 & ".com"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  Delay 1
Shell.SendKeys "username"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Shell.SendKeys "password"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Shell.SendKeys "admin debugsonus"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
For x = 0 To UBound(splitArray)
  splitArray1 = "configure call gcid " & splitArray(x) & " delete"
Shell.SendKeys splitArray1
next
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  Delay 1
Shell.SendKeys "exit"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  Delay 2
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Shell.SendKeys "exit"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
readfile
End Sub

Sub Delay( seconds )
  Dim wshShell
  Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  wshShell.Run "ping -n " & ( seconds + 1 ) & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
  Set wshShell = Nothing
End Sub

</script>
<script language="JScript" type="text/jscript">
<!--
function readFile()
 {
   var fso, fileHandle, contents, resultvar;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fileHandle = fso.OpenTextFile(document.editor.resultvar.value, 1);
   contents = fileHandle.ReadAll();
   if (contents)
     document.all("results").value = contents;
   fileHandle.close();
 }
//-->
</script>
<body>
<form name="editor">
<table>
  <tr>
<td align="right">Server Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"  size="18" id="serv1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Calls:</td>
<td><textarea size="18" id="call1" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
<td valign="bottom" align="left" colspan="2">
  <button type="submit" name="run_button"  onClick="ClearCalls">Clear Calls</button>
</td>
  <tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Results:</td>
<td><textarea cols="80" rows="20" name="results" id="results" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<td><input type="hidden" name="resultvar" value="c:\results.txt"></td>
</body>
```

If i use these variables in textarea call1

asd

asd

asd

asd

asd

asd

sad

i will get the following in results textarea

 configure call gcid asd

error: Incomplete command.  Expected one of: DELETE

  deleteconfigure call gcid asd

error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

  deleteconfigure call gcid asd
error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

  deleteconfigure call gcid asd

error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

  deleteconfigure call gcid asd

error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

  deleteconfigure call gcid asd

error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

  deleteconfigure call gcid sad delete

error: invalid command name "deleteconfigure"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `call2` contains `vbCrLf`s instead of the `vbLf` you are splitting for. Evidence:

```
>> a = Split( Join( Array( "a", "b", "c" ), vbCrLf ), vbLf )
>> For Each s In a
>>     WScript.Echo "xxxx" & s & "yyyy"
>> Next
>>
yyyya
yyyyb
xxxxcyyyy
```

Comment: THANKS, i didnt realize it was adding vbCrLf to the end i changed 2 lines and it works
    splitArray = Split(call2, vbCrLf, -1, 0
    Shell.SendKeys "configure call gcid " & splitArray(x) & " delete" & "{ENTER}"